# How to simpfly a complex Excel file

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a calculation and data storage heavy Excel file. About 90k rows of raw data, about 2500 calculations (some of which are dependent on other formulas), about 20 presentation worksheets (with a lot of VLOOKUP, INDEX/MATCH across the whole column )

I have simplified some of the data and now pull from a database rather than Excel files.

I can create the raw data via fuzzy database join (join using LIKE) but poor database performance (due organizational cheapness) makes this presently unviable (the concept works)

What I a more interested in is a way to simply the mass of formulas and calculate at database level. But I don't want to have to write some 2500 complex stored procedures

Power BI and Tableau look promising but the number of calculations and dataset size makes this somewhat unworkable. And the result is more reporting than visualization.

This feels like is should be solvable using a rules engine but the various rules engines I've looked at don't really cover this sort of area.

The challenge is that making changes to formulas necessitates a recalculate which takes time so changing and development is a slow process

Ideas?

Comment: What kind of rules engines you have been looking at? I use either PowerQuery or SQLite for ETL/ELT, and use DAX for the calculations at the last stage. Usually, I don’t have to change the formulas that often, though. DuckDB might be an alternative to SQLite speed-wise and “range” joins to simplify query modifications. KNIME is also strong in ETL and you can further analyze with ML (and DL) etc. on its workflow GUI (it has interface to Python and r codes as well)

Comment: As I don’t do this regularly or that often, I prefer these “low”-code solutions (except for SQL) where you can get results without remembering all the exact syntax and still can do more on code-level for specific requirements if needed.

Comment: Sample data always help for better understanding.